# Advice on Auditing VPN Connections

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn

I've inherited a network that is truly a mess and the VPN config is amazingly long with confusing group names and very little documentation. I am curious to see how others have gone about auditing these types of connections. Are there any forms out there? What information should I collect? I assume things like Customer, Department, Technical Lead, and etc.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this nightmare.

Comment: I'm always a little perplexed by these "auditing" questions. How would we have any idea what information is important to you? What information  are you looking to glean from this "audit"? Define that and you've got your answer. Not to be rude, but this question is akin to asking us what kind of sandwich you should make for your lunch. It's entirely dependent upon your needs and desires, not ours.

Comment: I don't think it's rude at all. I was more thinking that someone would have been through the same and had some sort of form or advice on something I haven't thought of. Wisdom of the crowds and such.

Comment: Gotcha. At the end of the day, we can give you generic advice but it's up to you to define what information is important to you and audit for that information.